# Chef - delete unused cookbooks from server

Tags: chef-infra

Over time we have developed multiple cookbooks and uploaded to our chef server. These cookbooks are used by multiple teams. Is there a way to check for a given cookbook which other cookbooks depend on it or which nodes use it in their run list? If it is not being used I should be able delete the cookbook from chef server. This will help us to clean up and not let new users use a deprecated cookbook.

Note: I want to run it against chef server (I even have Berkshelf api server) and not on local copies.

Thanks

Regards
Amod

Comment: Got answer from and it worked for me IRC #chef <@thom> Amod: just doing the search will show you everything in use
[12:53] <@thom> Oh, besides LWRPs. <@thom> Amod: knife search node "recipes:tomcat*"
[13:00] <@thom> (assuming your cookbook is called tomcat).

Comment: You may use [knife-audit](https://github.com/jbz/knife-audit) for this usage I think

Comment: Thanks a lot. The google search didn't return me that page :) BTW search does most of what I wanted.

Comment: In case it could be of some use: https://docs.chef.io/community_plugin_knife.html (docs.chef.io for all the documentation) and https://supermarket.chef.io (cookbooks and tooling around chef)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jbz/knife-audit

Install helper cookbook

"The helper cookbook (knife_audit) consists of a single recipe (default) with a single resource in it - a ruby_block which saves node.run_state.seen_recipes to the attribute node[:knife_audit][:seen_recipes]. This preserves the complete runlist information from seen_recipes, which chef-client does not save to the chef server after constructing it in the compile phase."

Ensure helper cookbook is run on all nodes to populate the attribute.

Only then will a knife-audit -a find everything inside nested dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Install Knife Audit

1. We need to have .chef/plugins/knife directory inside chef-repo. If you don’t have it then please make it using mkdir or any other method
2. Now create a file named audit.rb inside .chef/plugins/knife directory
3. visit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbz/knife-audit/master/lib/chef/knife/audit.rb
4. Copy the content and paste it in newly created audit.rb file
5. Install gem if not present -> `sudo yum install gem -y`
6. Install knife audit -> `gem install knife-audit`

Bash Script to delete unused cookbooks:-

1. Create a file `deleteUnusedCookbook.sh` inside chef-repo directory. Now paste the following code in `deleteUnusedCookbook.sh`

> #!/bin/bash
>  knife audit | tail -n +2 | awk '{ if($2 == 0) print $1;}'>unusedCookbook.txt
>  file=unusedCookbook.txt
>  for i in
> `cat $file`
>  do
>  knife cookbook delete "$i" -y
>  done

Here unusedCookbook.txt will contain the name of all unused cookbook on chef server. As a result In the script $2==0 will give the list of all unused cookbook. To get all used cookbook names change it to $2!=0 but please test it once without deleting otherwise it will delete all cookbooks which are currently in use.

2. Now, to make it executable please do -> `chmod +x deleteUnusedCookbook.sh`
3. Now run the script-> `./deleteUnusedCookbook.sh`